# i want to control stride in convolutional neural network but i dont know how to write stride

Tags: python, keras, stride

I am beginner of medical deep learning. I am practicing medical deep learning. I don't know how to control stride in ConVNN. I want to know if I control stride in ConVNN,that I think image is different. so I want to see that.

already I saw many information about stride in ConVNN in Keras. but I didn't understand.

```
def build_SRCNN():
    input_img = Input(shape=(512, 512, 1), name='image_input')


    x = Conv2D(64, (9, 9), strides=(1,1), activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(input_img)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), strides=(1,1), activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(x)

    # model
    SRCNN = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=x)

    return SRCNN
```

I wrote `stride = (1,1)` to `(3,3)` or `(5,5)` or `(7,7)` ... but error is same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting. As I checked, there is no error in `model` compilation. Also, please choose `strides` carefully as it can severely affect the performance of the model in terms of overall model accuracy.